# Bad class file-wrong version error when using JAR but its maven configuration target is properly set

Tags: java, android, maven, java-8, maven-compiler-plugin

I have been trying to make a library work with our Android project. Currently, we are getting errors with the library during our lint check:

```
bad class file: .....
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

So I've checked out the library in question and checked its `pom.xml`, it seems to be properly configured to be compatible with Java 8:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

The library developer and I assume that should be enough, or are we mistaken and should we use Java 8 when generating the library JAR? Or is the problem solely with me and should I use Java 11 instead of the bundled JDK with Android Studio?

Comment: The classes of the library should be compiled with the target as Java 8 for you to be able to use those class files. One can comment further, only looking at the library code and the way you are using it.

Comment: @Naman So what you mean is that the library project should use Java 8 for generating artifacts so that our Android project, which uses the built-in JDK , can use it?

Comment: The class files that you are trying to use are compiled with Java-11, while the version in use with your project seems to be Java-8. So whosoever is compiling those classes with Java-11 needs to make sure the target is 8.